# Remote Desktop Console Session - Desktop Icon

Tags: windows-7

Using a Windows 7 32-bit client I am trying to create a desktop icon which will allow me to login to a console session of Windows Server 2003.

When I open RDP via "mstsc /admin" and then login to the server it will connect to the console. However, if I open "mstsc /admin" and then try to save that profile to my desktop, it doesn't connect as the console session.

Using the same exact method with a Server 2008 RDP profile, I have no problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple.

Create the profile as you had before.

Instead of loading the profile to get to the server, create a shortcut which has

```
mstsc /admin c:\path\to\the\profile.rdp
```

in it.

That shortcut should then work for you.

Answer (score 1):

To add on, you can also create the shortcut `mstsc /admin /v:server.ip`